Can a caster level from a racial spell-like ability fullfill the requirement for a magic item creation feat?
Related :
Does a Qinggon monk fulfill the requirements to take craft magical arms and armor feat?
Does the caster level of a spell-like ability satisfy prerequisites of item creation feats?
These two thread are talking about requirement to take the feats. Which they do not.
The FAQ qualification clear this answer. Another FAQ tell us that having a specific spell-like ability (Like Fireball) can be used to meet prerequisite of an item requiring a fireball to be crafted.
But as far as I know, there is no word about the CASTER LEVEL. So here is the question: If an item requires you to have a CL of 9 to be crafted, and your character has a racial spell-like ability with a CL of 9, can it be used to meet this requirement?
(You can still otherwise skip this requirement entirely by adding a +5 to the DC, obviously, if that doesn't work.)

So you know, very few magic items have a caster level as one or their creation prerequisites (q.v. this answer and this answer).
